# Maximum function nesting level in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I know there are duplicates to this question, tried all of them, none of them worked. At last I commented out the zend_extension in php.ini, Now the browser keeps on processing endlessly.

**What I have**
I'm a calling a simple widget from my view

```
 echo \sintret\chat\ChatRoom::widget([
      'url' => \yii\helpers\Url::to(['/site/send-chat']),
      'userModel'=>  \common\models\User::className(),
      'userField' => 'avatarImage'
    ]);
```

**In my Controller:**

```
public function actionSendChat() {
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        echo \sintret\chat\ChatRoom::sendChat($_POST);
    }
}
```

Here is the Github link to [ChatRoom.php](https://github.com/sintret/yii2-chat-adminlte/blob/master/ChatRoom.php) which contains the main widget, it has only two main functions init() and run(). another is sendChat which we are calling in our controller.

Any thoughts to resolve the error are welcome.

Comment: It's probably easier to find the problem with xdebug enabled, look at the stack trace after it hits the nesting limit to see where the excessive function nesting is coming from, possibly an infinite recursion issue

Comment: I too suppose that it is an infinite recursion issue. Please see the link above and have a look at the two small functions init() and run() in  ChatRoom.php, I am hopeful that you can give an answer that I can accept.